# Batch: How To Specify Multiple Wildcards When Deleting Multiple Files In One Folder

Tags: batch-file

Hi I need some help with making a batch file to delete some png files that
are store in one folder essentially all I want to do is delete all files with
file name containing a `(` or a `_` how would I go about this

```
as del C:\directory goes here\?(?.png
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` is any *single* character, use `*` for zero-or-more characters:

```
del C:\directory goes here\*(*.png
del C:\directory goes here\*_*.png
```

Comment: Thanks man really helped me out, would upvote million times if I could, I've been searching for hours trying to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for two commands. You can specify multiple file masks with one DEL command. Use of quotes is a good idea to protect against spaces and poison characters.

```
del "C:\directory goes here\*(*.png" "C:\directory goes here\*_*.png"
```

Perhaps less typing if you work from the directory to be deleted:

```
pushd "C:\directory goes here"
del *(*.png *_*.png
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the wildcard is the star " * ". You can use this to tell the machine that you are looking for anything that fits the scheme. In your situation you are looking for something with the letter "a".png but you are unsure where the letter will be in the name. Try the following:

`del C:\directory\*a*.png`